# Rails joining same table twice under different dynamic scopes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I have an app in Rails 3.0.1 .  There is a table called Books which has many lists. I have conditional association with lists depending on whether they are good lists or bad lists.

```
#Book.rb
has_many :lists
has_many :good_lists, :foreign_key => 'book_id', :class_name => "List", :conditions => {:id => List.good_list_ids}
has_many :bad_lists, :foreign_key => 'book_id', :class_name => "List", :conditions => {:id => List.bad_list_ids}
```

Currently the conditions are cached when the app is started but I want it to be dynamic as the `good_list_ids` and `bad_list_ids` can change runtime. I want to be able to find books that are associated with both lists by chaining joins. For eg  if `good_lists_ids = [1,2,3]` and `bad_lists_ids = [4,5,6]`. I would like to get books that are associated with at least one `good_list_ids` and at least one `bad_list_ids`.

```
Book.joins(:good_lists).joins(:bad_lists)
```

I know it can be done by applying filters after fetching the records from db. But is there a way to do this only in sql using AREL?

Comment: what is the data type of good_list_ids and bad_list_ids

Comment: They are array of list ids. These arrays are updated by some other background process periodically.

Comment: I think your problem would be better solved with two scopes, have you considered it?

Comment: @zapico can u suggest how the scopes would look. I have considered it but do not know how to have them dynamic conditions and chainable as they depend on same association.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @zapico - use scopes. And you must use Lambda because `List.good_list_ids` and `List.bad_list_ids` are dynamic.

```
#Book.rb
has_many :lists    
scope :good_lists, -> { joins(:lists).where('lists.id IN (?)', List.good_list_ids) }
scope :bad_lists, -> { joins(:lists).where('lists.id IN (?)', List.bad_list_ids) }
```

**Update**

now you can get books which are in these lists

```
# in bad list
Book.bad_lists
# in good list
Book.good_lists
# in both lists (this is intersection! for these lists)
Book.bad_lists.good_lists
```

If you would like to have records belong to good_list OR bad_list then it seems to me the easiest way is

```
# join arrays
scope :good_bad_lists, -> { joins(:lists).where('lists.id IN (?)', List.good_list_ids | List.bad_list_ids) }
```

Comment: It works for dynamic conditions but when chaining the scopes it joins with lists having ids in both good and bad arrays, which is null. I want to have books that are associated with both good and bad lists. Updated the question with an example.

Comment: @tihom have you tried to ask for "uniq" values?? Book.bad_lists.good_lists.uniq

Comment: The question was improved by example and now it is clear that the problem is to get bad_list OR good_list. Chaining scopes gives operand `AND` in SQL query so the simplest way is to write one scope with joining these lists (bad_lists + good_lists). The answer has been updated.